# Configuring Varnish on cPanel with multiple IP addresses

Tags: apache, caching, cpanel, varnish

So I am trying to configure Varnish on my cPanel server which has a primary shared IP along with a few other secondary IP addresses for dedicated domains that are hosted with me.

I have followed the following guide on how to get varnish to run, and it works perfectly for the shared IP domains, but the secondary IP domains won't load at all, going to the default Apache page.

http://crybit.com/how-to-enable-varnish-in-cpanel-server/

I was looking online for other resources and found to configure multiple hosts in the default.vcl file for varnish, so I had done exactly that but the service fails to load as soon as I try launch it, even with just two hosts in the file.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
backend default {
  .host = "11.11.11.11";
  .port = "8080";
}

backend secondary1 {
  .host = "22.22.22.22";
  .port = "8080";
}
```

I have also tried configuring the following below but also to no success, service won't load!

```
sub vcl_recv{
  if(req.http.host == "www.secondary1.com") || (req.http.host == "secondary1.com) {
    set req.backend = secondary1;
  } else {
    set req.backend = default;
  }
}
```

Hoping that someone can give me a hand!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your /etc/sysconfig/varnish file and change your -a flag with your IP's.

```
-a 192.168.0.1:80,192.168.0.2:80 \
```

Comment: I've tried that and it still won't work. If i leave the DAEMON_OPTS as default, and just the sindlge backend in the default.vcl it works, but as soon as I add another backend in the default.vcl it fails.

Comment: Have you found any solution so you can share it ?